# I need to count date diff using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have file with dates:

```
Mar 16
Mar 12
Mar 13
Mar 19
Mar 14
Mar 17
```

and I need to calculate amount of days that passed till now. I come with this function:

```
datediff() {     
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s);     
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s);     
    echo $(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days; 
}
$ datediff 'now' '13 Mar'
114 days
```

but I need some loop that will calculate that for every line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop, where the condition is based on the ability to read from standard input:

```bsh
$ cat input.txt
Mar 16
Mar 12
Mar 13
Mar 19
Mar 14
Mar 17
$ cat ex.sh
#!/bin/bash

datediff() {
    local d1="$(date -d "$1" +%s)"
    local d2="$(date -d "$2" +%s)"

    echo "$(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days"
}

while read line; do
    datediff 'now' "${line}"
done < "${1}"
$ ./ex.sh input.txt
111 days
115 days
114 days
108 days
113 days
110 days
```

The script here takes a single argument: the input file.  While it can read a line from the file, it calls your `datediff` function passing `now` and the content of the `line` that it read from the file.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a shell loop here. You could do:

```
date -f file +%s |
  awk 'BEGIN{srand(); now = srand()}
       {print int((now - $0) / 86400), "days"}'
```

Note that `-d` and `-f` are extensions of the GNU implementation of `date`. Beware that `Dec 31` would be interpreted as `Dec 31` of *this year*, so in the future.

If you wanted to use a shell loop, you may prefer a shell that has builtin support for date manipulation like `zsh` or `ksh93`.

To interpret those timestamps as times in the past (where `Oct 10` is the most recent October 10 00:00:00 for instance), with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime || exit

now=$EPOCHSECONDS
strftime -s year %Y "$now"
(( lastyear = year - 1 ))
while IFS= read -r day; do
  strftime -rs t '%Y %b %d' "$year $day" || continue
  (( t <= now )) || strftime -rs t '%Y %b %d' "$lastyear $day"
  print $(( (now - t) / 86400 ))
done < file
```

That one also has the benefit of understanding the month name abbreviations of the user in addition to the English ones.

Comment: +1. Perhaps it was intentional, but note that depending on when the script is run and how long it takes (e.g. Dec 31, 23:59:59 for > 1 second), since `now` and `lastyear` are being evaluated outside of the loop, depending on expectations, it could provide inaccurate results.

Comment: @JohnB, it seems to me it would make more sense for all the results to be calculated based on the same time (the time the user invokes the script). That's what `find` does for instance for its `-mtime`/`-mmin` even though it's not so uncommon for `find` to take several minutes to run. I had an issue though in that `year` and `now` were not computed based on the same instant in time. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reliable calendar support is a hard problem and I'd recommend using a dedicated program for it. Luckily, someone did the hard work for us.

from http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/datemath.html :

> Too many times we have needed to do a bit of math on a date -- say, "today + 7 days" -- but in traditional MM/DD/YYYY format this is really tricky (especially in a shell script). A result of this need we built the datemath tool which can perform these functions from the command line or from a shell script. Examples:

```
$ datemath today + 5
06/23/2003

$ datemath '12/25/2003 - today'
188

$ datemath today + 5 weeks
07/25/2003

when will my machine be up for one year?
$ uptime
 11:09am  up 317 days, 15:38,  7 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.04, 0.01
$ datemath today + 365 - 317
10/24/2003
```

You can download the source code from the website and build it.